# Average over last 30 days not including current record (mixed date and row-based condition)

Tags: oracle, window-functions

I'm working on a column called `CRD_TRX_SYAMT_AVG_30d` which fills these criteria:

- Computes average of `SYSTEMAMOUNT` column over last 30 days according to `TRXHOSTDATETIME`
- Excluding rows where `RESPONSECODE` is not 00
- Excluding the current record

There's complete sample data below. And I've pasted this into DB Fiddle, but there's an issue preventing the code from running there. For me, it runs fine in SQL Developer but gives unexpected results.

I've tried substituting CURRENT ROW with 1 PRECEDING, but it's not possible to mix an interval and a range to my understanding. The column `CRD_TRX_SYAMT_AVG_30_trx_exc` uses a row-based condition (ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) and this works fine. So the issue is only with `CRD_TRX_SYAMT_AVG_30d`.

How can I change the condition to something like the following?

```
RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '30' DAY PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=471da47ef5df960b67e427053e7642d4

```
-- DATE formatting
alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

-- DROP and CREATE TABLE
DROP TABLE TMP_EXA_RSS_ISS_AUT_S_100CRD_T;

CREATE TABLE "RAI"."TMP_EXA_RSS_ISS_AUT_S_100CRD_T" 
 (  "ID_KEY_HASH" VARCHAR2(10), 
"TRXHOSTDATETIME" DATE, 
"SYSTEMAMOUNT" NUMBER(10,1), 
"RESPONSECODE" CHAR(2)
 );

 -- fill entire table
DECLARE
  nTRX NUMBER(10) := 100;
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1 .. nTRX LOOP
  INSERT INTO tmp_exa_RSS_ISS_AUT_S_100CRD_T VALUES
  (
    FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (1, 4)), -- ID_KEY_HASH
    TO_DATE('01.01.2018', 'DD.MM.YYYY') + dbms_random.value(0, 60), -- TRXHOSTDATETIME
    FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (1, 10)) * 100, -- SYSTEMAMOUNT
    CASE round(dbms_random.value(1,11)) 
            WHEN 1 THEN '55' 
            WHEN 2 THEN '88'
            ELSE '00'
       END -- RESPONSECODE 
  );
END LOOP;
END;
/

-- review all data created
SELECT * FROM tmp_exa_RSS_ISS_AUT_S_100CRD_T ORDER BY ID_KEY_HASH, TRXHOSTDATETIME;


-- example features:

SELECT ID_KEY_HASH, TRXHOSTDATETIME, SYSTEMAMOUNT, RESPONSECODE,
ROUND(AVG(
  CASE WHEN ((SYSTEMAMOUNT > 0) AND (RESPONSECODE = '00')  ) THEN SYSTEMAMOUNT ELSE NULL END
) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_KEY_HASH ORDER BY TRXHOSTDATETIME 
                        RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '30' DAY PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), 2)  AS CRD_TRX_SYAMT_AVG_30d,
NVL( ROUND( 
  AVG(
      CASE WHEN ((SYSTEMAMOUNT > 0) AND (RESPONSECODE = '00')  ) THEN SYSTEMAMOUNT ELSE NULL END
      ) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY ID_KEY_HASH ORDER BY TRXHOSTDATETIME NULLS LAST 
      ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
  , 2), 0 ) AS CRD_TRX_SYAMT_AVG_30_trx_exc
FROM tmp_exa_RSS_ISS_AUT_S_100CRD_T
ORDER BY ID_KEY_HASH, TRXHOSTDATETIME
;
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Instead of a FOR .. LOOP just use INSERT's, but give us a working example otherwise we cant test it

Comment: I've fixed the fiddle for you: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9ac3c925e78d4203224852002411d95e but I think this fiddle is not suited to test a big demo with hudreds rows like this one, since it only shows max. 10 rows.

Comment: The problem with using random values is that we don't know what the result should be; if you provided fixed inserts then you could include your expected results, and have something more concrete to aim for and test against. You might just want `RANGE BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING` but it's hard to tell at the moment.

Comment: How about: `range between interval '30' day preceding and interval '1' second preceding`? This should work as long as you can't have duplicate date-time for the same `ID_KEY_HASH`.

Comment: @AlexPoole - the problem with using random values can be mitigated. To create a reproducible test case while using random values, the seed must first be set to a fixed value. This will cause all the "randomly generated" values to be deterministic: anyone else who wants to recreate the data can run the same code, with the same assignment to the seed first.

Comment: Then it isn't really random *8-) but I take your point and agree. The main point I was making was that the OP didn't give expected results; which they could have done if they'd included a seed, as you say.

Comment: I've attempted to set a seed for the random number generator here but it isn't working. The same code worked fine in SQL Developer. Does anyone have an idea why? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5cb206067e0880aebe4533920f07073f

Comment: I understand now that next time, I should discuss the results that I achieved and explain what my desired results would be. I'll keep that in mind. Otherwise was my question structure and formatting OK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the composite `(ID_KEY_HASH, TRXHOSTDATETIME)` is unique (no duplicate date-times for the same ID_KEY_HASH), then the following expression will do what you require:

```
 avg(case when systemamount > 0 and responsecode = '00' then systemamount end)
   over (partition by id_key_hash order by TRXHOSTDATETIME 
         range between interval '30' day preceding 
                   and interval '1' second preceding)
```

You can wrap it within `ROUND( ... , 2)` if needed.

Comment: I think this assumption will work for my use case. I put your solution on DB Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5cb206067e0880aebe4533920f07073f. I'm not sure why, but the seed for the random number generator isn't working.